# Running mmvec example

Tags: python, tensorflow

I want to installed mmvec on my desktop computer from this link:
https://github.com/biocore/mmvec

But when I try to run this example:

"mmvec paired-omics \
    --microbe-file examples/cf/otus_nt.biom \
    --metabolite-file examples/cf/lcms_nt.biom \
    --summary-dir summary",

But after running these commands, it shows the following error at the end:

"ImportError: cannot import name 'dense_features' from 'tensorflow.python.feature_column' (/home/narges/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/feature_column/init.py)"

In addition, when I run tensorboard --logdir . , it shows the following error at the end:

"AttributeError: module 'tensorflow' has no attribute 'estimator'"

Could you please guide me what might be the problem? I could previously run this example, but I do not know what happened that it is not working anymore.

Thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

This might help you.

https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/13856

Most people have environment problem. Read it and try to see where you have gone wrong.